# Running complex web apps locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I downloaded a chat template online called [shout](https://github.com/erming/shout).  When I upload the chat template to heroku, it works fine.  However, when I simply doubleclick its `index.html` in my local browser, it doesn't work.  The page refreshes every milisecond.  Is this an error specific to what I downloaded, or this is a common phenomenon?  If so, is there a way around it?

Comment: Start a local server

Comment: Why was this down voted with no comment given?  Please leave comment if you down vote so others can learn.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your browser or computer. Based on the language of that chat template, you need to run a server on your local machine to test your app in localhost environment. Most of the popular languages like PHP, Java, ASP, etc run fine on XAMP and WAMP. Just google for one of them, install and voila, you have a server running. Then you can open the index.html as usual and get it working like on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a local server to do the http requests.

If you are on a PC download mamp:

http://www.mamp.info/en/

If you are on OSx check out tutorials by the coolest guy on the planet blog:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/